# Android Compatibility package and getLoaderManager()

Tags: android, android-loadermanager

[Android Compatibility package](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/fragments-for-all.html) is said to support LoaderManager. How can I get an instance of LoaderManager? The getLoaderManager() method is missing in FragmentActivity, it's only in Fragment class. But I want to use only Loaders, not Fragments in my app.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Based on my reading of the source, call `getSupportLoaderManager()` on your ACL `FragmentActivity`.