# getLoaderManager.initLoader() can't be resolved under API level 10 in Android

Tags: android

in Android : 
I want to use the method : `getLoaderManager.initLoader()` with API level 10 .
I know that this method requires API Level 11 or higher and i tried to use Android Support package but this package doesn't have this method . 
what can i do ??

Answer (score 2):

It sure looks to me like the Android Support Package has it. See the docs for [`android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.initLoader()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/LoaderManager.html#initLoader%28int,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks%3CD%3E%29).

**Update:**

For the equivalent of `getLoaderManager`, see [`getSupportLoaderManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportLoaderManager%28%29).

Comment: There is getLoader() , not getLoaderManager !

Comment: Updated with `getLoaderManager` equivalent. Also see this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763514/android-compatibility-package-and-getloadermanager).

Comment: it looks like that getSupportLoaderManager work with FragmentActivity ,, i want to use getLoaderManager() with ListActivity !

Comment: Consider using `FragmentActivity` along with [`ListFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the minimum SDK to level 15 and it will work fine.